# RegEx for extracting certain number of chars before the last hyphen

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Hi I want to extract the dates in a dataframe column and the dates are separated by "-" or "to"

```
 pop       DATE                     
 0  1.5   OWREAP-01/06/18to30/06/18  
 1  1.7   OW - 01/07/18 - 30/08/18     
 2  3.6   BCREAP - 01/08/18 to 30/08/18 
 3  2.4   BCGRA TO 01/08/18 to 30/08/18
```

I tried to replace "to" and "TO" with "-"

```
df['DATE'].str.replace('to|TO','-')
 pop       DATE                     
 0  1.5   OWREAP-01/06/18-30/06/18  
 1  1.7   OW - 01/07/18 - 30/08/18     
 2  3.6   BCREAP - 01/08/18 - 30/08/18 
 3  2.4   BCGRA - 01/08/18 - 30/08/18
```

Now I need to know how to extract 8 characters before and after the last hyphen
i.e

```
 pop       type   startdate enddate                    
 0  1.5   OWREAP  01/06/18  30/06/18  
 1  1.7   OW      01/07/18  30/08/18     
 2  3.6   BCREAP  01/08/18  30/08/18 
 3  2.4   BCGRA   01/08/18  30/08/18
```

Comment: You should use regex for this. I'm going to add the label and let the regex-sharks handle the rest.

Comment: Why not just `split` on `' - '` and take the last two items? Cc. @AntonvBR

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well, looking at the original dataframe we could skip the intermediary step to replace to/TO and by using regex we make sure we get dates of correct format. But, you are not wrong. There are other ways to solve it.

Comment: `r'([0-9\/]+)\s\S+\s([0-9\/]+)'` works for me as the regex string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
reg = r'(?i).*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\s*(?:TO|-)\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)'
df[['startdate','enddate']] = df.pop('DATE').str.extract(reg)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WZXoli/3).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)` - Start date capturing group: 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/`, 2 or 4 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:to|-)` - `to` or `-`
- `\s*`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)` - End date capturing group: 2 digits, `/`, 2 digits, `/`, 2 or 4 digits

Python test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'DATE': ["OWREAP-01/06/18to30/06/18"],
                    'dummy': ["value"]})
reg = r'(?i).*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)\s*(?:to|-)\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?)'
df[['startdate','enddate']] = df.pop('DATE').str.extract(reg)
>>> df
   dummy startdate   enddate
0  value  01/06/18  30/06/18
```

Comment: This is brilliant but what if it is -"01/06/2018to30/06/2018" in some cases? how to I the uncertain number of characters after "/ "?

Answer (score 1):

Split using `splat = df.DATE.str.split(expand=True)` to get:

```
        0   1         2   3         4
0  OWREAP   -  01/06/18  to  30/06/18
1      OW   -  01/07/18   -  30/08/18
2  BCREAP   -  01/08/18  to  30/08/18
3   BCGRA  TO  01/08/18  to  30/08/18
```

Then `splat[2]` is your `startdate` column, and `splat[4]` is `enddate`.

Comment: Thanks but  this would not work if there is not space in between, I have changed the post to reflect it.

Comment: OK, well given that you already know how to convert "to" into "-", and now I've shown you `split()`, note that `split()` has the option to specify the separator character.  I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: ``` df2['DATE2']=df2['DATE'].str.replace('to|TO','-')
df2['endDATE']=df2['DATE'].str.split('-').str[-1]
df2['starDATE']=df2['DATE'].str.split('-').str[-2]```Thanks used this to figure it out